# Slack Workflow Builder url formatting

Tags: workflow, slack, builder

I'm trying to format a message using Slack Workflow Builder, but it doesn't work.

I prepare a text as single variable and pass it to Slack webhook.
In Slack Workflow Builder I receive it and send a message just placing that single variable content into text message. A message looks good, but cannot succeed to format a link in a message.

I tried the following formats: `[Link](http://link.com)` and `<http://link.com|Link>`.
These two outputs wrong as is with all brackets without formatting.
But when I send the first variant `[Link](http://link.com)` into Slackbot it works as expected - it shows just clickable `Link`.

What am I doing wrong?
Does Slack support url formatting in Slack Workflow Builder?
How can I do it in there?

**Upd:** I also tried moving a link or its part into a separate variable and I've noticed, that placing a variable into a link (into round brackets) immediately breaks it in Preview area:
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have an official answer from Slack that constructing urls using variables is not yet supported in Slack Workflow Builder.

Comment: Same problem here, I want to have constructed links from variables.  Thanks for letting me know Im wasting my time... a pity Slack havent provided this functionality

Comment: If they ever do it, could you please update this answer?

Comment: I NEED THIS FEATURE

Comment: need it as well